# AngularJS UI Router Smart-Table integration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router, smart-table

I am quite new to angularJS so this might be way less complex than I think it is.
I have a huge JSON DataSet that I am displaying using SmartTable and I am trying to save a multiple table filter (Using check-boxes) using UI router. 
I have been Playing around with UI Router and it seems like I would have to manually create routes.
I also found this [example](http://angular-data-grid.github.io/demo/bootstrap/ui-router.html) using a different datagrid but I can't get it to load.
I unfortunately can't share code (Company policy) but it was mainly based on this [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/lu30E4WYjCSuFlayECxF/)

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: How do I get A smart table filter saved as a Route